# Change colours in UltraEdit's Compare Files

Tags: ultraedit

Is there a way to change the colours used in the Compare Files function in UltraEdit (menu *File* -> *Compare Files...*)?

The software displays the differences in yellow and red. While it makes the differences stand out, the highlighted text is hard to read.

I'm currently using version 9.0, but I'm open to hearing about other versions.

Comment: That is the separate application *[UltraCompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare/pro_vs_lite.html)*, right? Is it the "Lite" or "Pro" version?

Comment: No.  It's part of the Menu.  I have the UltraEdit-32 Professional/Hex Editor Version 9.

Comment: Doesn't a *separate* application start when you press the button "Compare" in dialog "Compare Files/Folders" (it does in UltraEdit version 16.20.0.1010)?

Comment: Apparently, yes.  Clicking on Compare Files invokes UEDIFF.EXE.  The options available in the UE-Compare window are: Save, Print, Prev and Next.  Does version 16 allow you to select the colours?  If so, I may have to update my version.